# How to remove all data from a file before a line containing string by passing variable in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to trim the data above the line from a file, where line containing some string by passing variable to it

```
varfile=$(cat variable.txt)
echo "$varfile"
if [ -z "$varfile" ]; then
    echo "null"
else
    echo "data"
sed "1,/$varfile/d" fileee.txt
fi
```

Here I am taking a string from variable.txt file and trying to find that text in fileee.txt file and removing all the data above the line

EX: variable.txt has 3
I am finding 3 in  fileee.txt and removing data above three

```
INPUT:
1
2
3
4
OUTPUT:
3
4
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted? How is it not providing your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the issue here is that you want to remove all lines *before* the match, but not the matching line itself?

One way, with GNU sed, is to explicitly add a print for the matching line first:

```
pattrn=3
seq 1 4 | sed -e "/$pattrn/p;1,/$pattrn/d"
```

Though this will duplicate any further lines that match the pattern.

Better, invert the sense of the match:

```
seq 1 4 | sed -ne "/$pattrn/,\$p"
```

That is, don't print by default (`-n`), but print (`p`) anything from a match to the end (`$`, escaped because of the double-quoted string)

Even better would be to use `awk`:

```
pattrn=3
seq 1 4 | awk -vpat="$pattrn" '$0 ~ pat {p=1} p'
```

This sets a flag on the line where the whole line (`$0`) matches the pattern (`~` is a regex match), then prints the lines whenever that flag is set.

The `awk` solution is also better in that special characters in the pattern don't cause issues (at least not as many); in the `sed` case, if the pattern contains a slash `/`, it will terminate the regex in the `sed` code, and cause syntax errors or allow for code injection.

I used `seq` from GNU coreutils here only to make up the sequence of numbers for input.